# Assigning a value from a cell array to a numerical arrray

Tags: matlab

How to assign a value from a cell array to a numerical array efficiently? A and B are always square matrices of any size. For simplicity I just allocated small matrices. If for example A{1}=[2 3 8]; then I want allocate value 8 in second row and third column of the B matrix.
E.g.,

```
 Input 

  A=[1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]   [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]   [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]   [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]   [1x3 double]


 B=zeros(4,4);

 A{1}=[2 3 8];
 A{2}=[3 4 7];
 and so on...

 Output
 B(2,3)=8;
 B(3,4)=7;
 and so on...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`spconvert`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spconvert.html):

```
B = full(spconvert(cat(1, A{:})));
```

Comment: Nice one-liner :) can i borrow that `A{:}` part with your permission :P ? it saves me 2 line XD ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without loops:

```
B=zeros(4,4);

A{1}=[2 3 8];
A{2}=[3 4 7];

C = cell2mat(A);
C = reshape(C,3,size(C,2)/3)';
indices =  sub2ind(size(B), C(:,1), C(:,2));
B(indices) = C(:,3);
```

For your example this results in:

```
B =

 0     0     0     0
 0     0     8     0
 0     0     0     7
 0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Apologies.. mine ended up similar to yours! +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sub2ind` and `indexing`

```
%// creating a sample cell array. Replace this with your actual cell array
A = {[1 2 8] [1 1 4]; [2 1 5] [2 2 1]};

%// Reshaping the cell array to kx3 matrix
Amat = cat(1,A{:});          %// from luis' answer

%// taking first column as row sub, 2nd col as col sub
%// The subs are converted into linear indices to the size of A or B
ind = sub2ind(size(A),Amat(:,1),Amat(:,2));

%// You have done this (helps in fixing the dimensions of B)
B = zeros(size(A));

%// Taking last col of 'Amat' as values and assigning to corresponding indices
B(ind) = Amat(:,3);
```

**Results:**

```
>> B

B =

 4     8
 5     1
```

Comment: maybe yours is slightly faster since you do not need to transpose the matrix

Comment: @m.s. Or may be not.. I reshaped to 3D instead

Comment: @Santhan Salai If I replace your A with my A above, I get an error: "Error using sub2ind
Out of range subscript."

Comment: @user3080956 that should be logical error. your 1st and 2nd values of each cell should be in this range `1-4`. Or else Edit your question to add the actual matrix

Comment: @Santhan SalaiA and B are always square matrices. Elements of cell array A are row, column and value of the B matrix. I want to assign values to their appropriate locations in the matrix B.

Comment: @user3080956 Do this `mat2cell(A)` in cmd window and please add the results to your question as an edit. That would be easy for us.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looping once over the A cells to find the maximum index values, let's say `max_i,max_j`.

Then initialize B like:

```
B=zeros(max_i,max_j)
```

And loop again over the A cells and assign th values to the corresponding B elements.

Edit: Added example code:

```
max_i=0
max_j=0
for k=1:size(A,1)
    for l=1:size(A,2)
         max_i=max([A{k,l}(1),max_i])
         max_j=max([A{k,l}(2),max_j])
end

B=zeros(max_i,max_j)

for k=1:size(A,1)
    for l=1:size(A,2)
         B(A{k,l}(1),A{k,l}(2))=A{k,l}(3)
end
```

Comment: A and B are always square matrices of any size. A for loop will be too slow for large matrices